# Reading large CSV file with Pandas freezes computer

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working with a relatively large CSV file in Python. I am using the pandas `read_csv` function to import it. The data is on a shared folder at work and around 25 GB.

I have 2x8 GB RAM and an Intel Core i5 processor and using the juypter notebook. While loading the file the RAM Monitoring goes up to 100%. It stays at 100% or 96% for some minutes and then my computer clock stopped and my screen is frozen. Even if I wait 2 hours my computer is not able to use any more, so I have to restart.

My question is:
Do I need to split the data? Would it help? Or is it a general performance problem with my laptop?

It is the first time that I am working with such a 'large' dataset (I still think 25 GB is not too much.)

Comment: How many times did this happen?

Comment: You're hitting your physical ram limits, so you're observing your swap file being thrashed, if the data won't fit in memory you need to use a different method such as using `pytables` and `hdfs`

Comment: @Denziloe always with this file

Comment: You may want to look at dask http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/docs.html. I did not try it but it looks promising.

Comment: right now i am trying: `tp = pd.read_csv('RawdataEurope.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000)` and `df = concat(tp, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: this is working, the RAM is still fully on use, but python is able to give me the dataframe. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For large files, pandas can read them in chunks.

```
chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    process(chunk)
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) of `read_csv`. There is a parameter called `nrows`. It states:

> nrows : int, default None
>
> Number of rows of file to read. Useful for reading pieces of large files

You can loop through the file reading only a few lines at a time, this way not the whole file will be loaded into RAM.

By the way: using something like:

```
with open(my_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

Will only load one line into memory at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably loading all of the data in your RAM, thus allocating all memory available, forcing your system to rely on swap memory (writing temporary data to the disk, which is MUCH slower).

It should solve the issue if you split the data into chunks that fit in your memory. Maybe 1 GB each?